# Replacing Motobecane 500 HT derailleur hanger

Tags: shimano, derailleur

Can I just replace my rear derailer hanger in order to fix my derailer, is that an option?  It looks like it broke and it definitely is detachable.

Comment: In fact, a photo of the state of the matters would likely to help with providing additional diagnostics on whether it is just a derailleur hanger should be replaced, or the derailleur itself is cooked.

Comment: I recently dealt with a supplier who guaranteed fit, if you sent them pictures of the rear end and a few other details.  Unfortunately, I don't have the supplier's info at hand (and of course we're officially not supposed to provide it anyway), but such service is out there, and (in this case) quite reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you will need to buy a replacement part that is specifically designated for your bicycle vendor, model and even model year combination as there is close to none compatibility between derailleurs.

You can search the net for the words "[bicycle name] + derailleur". Some companies in some countires offer wide catalogs of compatible parts. Some of these folks can even cut a new part with a CNC machine for you. In this case, contact them and provide the information they will request. Most likely they will need photoes and measurements of the derailleur and/or dropout where it sits.

Note that replacements derailleurs are relatively cheap, and even making a custom part is much cheaper than buying a new bike. And while you are at it, why not order an extra part, just for the future?

Answer (score 0):

How did you break your rear derailleur hanger? If your bike fell on the rear derailleur most likey the derailleur itself will have some damage too.

You could try replacing the hanger first and then have a look if you can adjust the rear derailleur correctly afterwards. If it won't shift correctly you will also need a new one and adjust it.
In case you need a new one you should buy one thats suitable for the same amount of gears.